# Powering an onboard car GPS tracker

Tags: power, batteries, dc, battery-charging, dc-dc-converter

I made a car tracker (a GPS/LTE module connected to an arduino that communicate to my web server) to log gps positionning data. I’m planning to use this to track my new car in case it gets stolen.

My initial thought would be to hot-wire the tracker to the car’s 12V battery followed by a DC-DC converter to 5V.

For redundancy I was planning to also power the tracker from an 18650 battery in case the thief disconnect the car’s battery.

My issue is that I’d like to use the car’s battery as the primary source of power, then the integrated 18650 battery. Finally the car’s battery would be used to charge the 18650 when needed.

The tracker would be low power usage (eg sending location every 10min, in sleep mode other wise).

What would be the best way of powering such system without draining the car’s battery with multiple DC converters ?

Comment: How are you thinking of connecting these together? What you describe seems odd... I would use a dc to dc converter to power the device from the car battery.

Comment: Can you run the GPS/LTE module at raw Li-Ion (3.8-4.2V) battery voltage, and the Arduino (AVR) at 3.3V? That would make this design somewhat easier to work with...

Comment: It seems so. The GPS/LTE module I use is based on the SIM7000 chip (Supply voltage range: 3.0V~ 4.3V, Typ: 3.8V). The GPS antenna may need a bit more to provide correct satellite reception though ?

Comment: @Fredovsky -- what do the specs on the antenna say?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I just checked and the antenna accepts 2.7V-5V, so indeed I'm not restricted to 5V. Thanks I'm getting on the right tracks already.

Comment: @Fredovsky -- do you have any limitations on what chip packages you can use, for that matter?

Comment: Also, are you planning to use a bare 18650, or a cell that has a protection circuit as part of the package?

Comment: Regarding the GPS/4G I bought the SIM7000 for this purpose and got a working prototype, but if better chips/modules are suggested I'm happy to change if necessary. The Arduino is also used because I had one at hand but I can swap. I'm still at the prototyping and was getting started on the power management issues 
before moving forward so I'm pretty flexible.

Comment: I'll be using a battery cell with protection circuit as I don't want my car to burn down if I make something wrong.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I mis-read your question. thru-hole and SMD components are fine, as long as they can be hand soldered without too much trouble.

Comment: @Fredovsky -- one last thing -- are you familiar with using the brown-out reset on AVRs, as well as the undervoltage shutoff function on the SIM7000?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I've never had to use those, but I'm happy to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being put on the right track by @ThreePhaseEel, I found pretty much a chip dedicated to exactly my application (except it isn't coming in an easy to solder by hand package, but not impossible) : [Analog LTC4091](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4091fa.pdf).

> The LTC®4091 is a 36V Li-Ion battery charger and power
>   backup manager. The integrated step-down switching
>   regulator charges a battery from a primary power source
>   while providing power to the load. If primary power is lost,
>   the load is seamlessly transitioned to the backup Li-ion/
>   polymer battery.
>
> Applications :
>
> - Fleet and Asset Tracking
> - Automotive GPS Data Loggers
> - Automotive Telematics Systems
> - Battery Backup Systems

For those looking for a similar application, there are dedicated IC that deal with battery charging called `Battery Manager IC`.

The feature switching from main power supply to the battery supply if power is removed (ie. using the battery as backup power), is generally called `Power Path Management`.

Comment: Looks promising. How is it working ? I have two queries on it for the case when car is idle for long period.
1. suppose if we connect it directly with car battery and car is idle for long period (say month) then gps will run on lipo and lipo will be keep on sucking charge from battery. This may drain car battery. 
2. If we connect it with ignition then lipo may not drain car battery but lipo itself will be drained completely if car is idle. 

Won't it be good to power device from lipo only and turn off LTC4091 when lipo is 100% charged and turn on LTC4091 when lipo is 15% charged ?

Comment: I am planning to track my bike and i want my device to be always ON. your case may drain my bike battery if bike is idle for long. I want device to power from bike battery/alternator when bike is moving and want to power from lipo when bike is not moving. But if bike is idle for long and lipo is getting drained then i want to auto turn LTC4091 to charge lipo from bike battery. So basically, i would like to control LTC4091 based on my lipo charge capacity.

Answer (score 1):

### You need to solve two problems here: battery charging and undervoltage lockout

The good news is that the voltage range of your parts (the Arduino's AVR microcontroller and the SIM7000 module) is wide enough that once we step the voltage down for your 18650, we do not need to mess with it any further -- they will run just as well on 4.2V from a fully charged cell as they will from the 3.something volts from an empty one.  However, we will still want an undervoltage/brownout protector to keep the cell's protection circuit from having to kick in on a regular basis, and we will also need a suitable charge controller that can take car "12V" and charge the battery.

While Li-Ion charging facilities are common, most of them run off of 5V, not directly off of the variable "12V" automotive supply voltage, and so it goes for the SIM7000 module's charger, rendering it not useful for our application.  As a result of this, we need to look further afield for a battery charger IC, and Linear Technology (now part of Analog Devices) comes through with the [LTC4002-4.2](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/linear-technology-analog-devices/LTC4002ES8-4.2-PBF/LTC4002ES8-4.2-PBF-ND/962617).

At under $4 in unit quantities, it is not particularly expensive, and with the addition of a P-channel MOSFET, two Schottky diodes, and a handful of passives, it provides a complete step-down switching battery charging solution.  It also comes in an easy-to-solder SO-8 package, and is well-documented, with detailed design procedures and simulation models (using LTspice, of course).  Paired with a low-loss PMOS in SO-8 or IPAK, a couple of 20V/3A Schottky diodes, and a suitable inductor with at least 2A of current handling capability, it will be able to both charge the battery and handle the current draw spikes of the SIM7000 module.

This leaves undervoltage protection, and this is easy -- just about any reset supervisor IC with a threshold in the 3.3-3.6V range can be used, as holding both the AVR and the SIM7000 in reset will put them into a low-power-draw state.  Optionally, the supervisor can also provide manual-reset and/or watchdog timer functionality as well, as the watchdog may need to reset both the AVR and the SIM7000 to clear a hung condition.

Comment: I really appreciate your input. Can you confirm that the PMOS would be connected to the GATE pin of the battery charging chip, and its function is to select power from the car's battery (clamped to 8V below according to the datasheet (=4V)), or, if the car's battery isn't available, to provide power from the Li-ion battery ?

Comment: @Fredovsky you have the right idea with how the PMOS is wired, but it's actually doing something more sophisticated than what you think.  The LTC4002 is actually stepping down the voltage from 12V to 4.2V using a *buck converter* topology, switching the PMOS on and off to regulate the charge voltage going to the Li-Ion cell (and thus, to the rest of the circuit).

Comment: I see, so when the Li-Ion cell is fully charged after a charging cycle, the rest of the circuit will be draining power from the Li-Ion until its charge drops below a limit at which point the LTC4002 kicks in again and tops-up the Li-Ion? My concern is that we'd be constantly draining/charging the Li-Ion (maybe causing premature wear), where we could use the 12V car battery (if available) instead, saving Li-Ion charge cycles.

Comment: @Fredovsky -- the Li-Ion will be sitting at its 4.2V float voltage, sipping power to keep it from *self-discharging*, while the rest of the circuit runs.  It's *slightly* naughty to do this with a Li-Ion (float charging is more of a lead-acid thing) but not as bad as one thinks, AIUI